# from scrapy.selector import selector error

Tags: python, macos, web-scraping, scrapy, lxml

I am unable to do the following:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
```

The error is:

File "/Desktop/KSL/KSL/spiders/spider.py", line 1, in 
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
ImportError: cannot import name Selector

It is as if LXML is not installed on my machine, but it is.  Also, I thought this was a default module built into scrapy.  Maybe not?

Thoughts?

Comment: `from scrapy.selector import Selector` corresponds to the new unified selector API. If you're following http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#constructing-selectors (version 0.19) you'll need to install Scrapy from source. Scrapy 0.19 has not been released on PyPI officially

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try importing **HtmlXPathSelector** instead.

```
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
```

And then use the **.select()** method to parse out your html.  For example,

```
    sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    site_names = sel.select('//ul/li')
```

If you are following the tutorial on the Scrapy site (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), the updated example would look like this:

```
    from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

    class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
        name = "dmoz"
        allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
        start_urls = [
            "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
            "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
        ]

        def parse(self, response):
            sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            sites = sel.select('//ul/li')

            for site in sites:
                title = site.select('a/text()').extract()
                link = site.select('a/@href').extract()
                desc = site.select('text()').extract()
                print title, link, desc
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works, but you're missing a colon at the definition of parse(). I'd edit it, but stackoverflow has that weird 6 character minimum for editing....

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem. I think there is something wrong with your scrapy version.

You could type `scrapy version -v` into cmd to check the version.  As far as I know, the newest version is 0.24.4 (2014.10.23). You could visit http://scrapy.org/ to find the newest.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue which was due to the way I installed scrapy (my OS is Ubuntu). I did it through

```
sudo apt-get install python-scrapy
```

Install it from python instead. If you use Anaconda just do

```
conda install -c scrapinghub scrapy
```

If not, then

```
pip install Scrapy
```

[http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html](http://source)