# Select all element with particular id patern in python scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape a website.
I want to select all elements with id of the form 'result_%s' where %s is any integer.

```
sites.select('//*[@id="result_1"]')
```

How can it be achieved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scrapy, the main way to pull information out of a page is with `Selector`s. The most popular way to use Scrapy's Selectors is with Xpath expressions.

Xpath has a few handy functions, one of which is `contains()`. You can use it in your spider like so:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class ExampleSpider(Spider):
    name = "exampleSpider"
    start_urls = ["http://example.com/sitemap.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        results = sel.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'result_')]")
        for result in results:
            #do something with the results here
            print result.extract()
```

It checks to see if the second argument is a substring of the first.

The [Official Scrapy Tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) is a great resource if you want to learn more about structuring your spider and extracting data from a page.

Comment: @ScrapyNovice  its giving me an error             divs=sites.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'result_')]")
        exceptions.AttributeError: 'XPathSelectorList' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Comment: user2129794: What is the result of `type(sites)`? It should be `Selector`.

Comment: @ScrapyNovice sites = hxs.select('//html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div')

Comment: @user2129794: It looks like you're using BeautifulSoup. Is that correct?

With Scrapy, you can use Selectors, so you don't need to use BeautifulSoup at all. 

    `sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath("//html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div")
    results = sites.xpath("./*[contains(@id, 'result_')]")
    for result in results:
        print result.extract()`

Comment: @ScrapyNovice   m getting this error  from scrapy.selector import Selector
ImportError: cannot import name Selector

Comment: @ScrapyNovice m not using beautifulsoup... am using HtmlXPathSelector instead of Selector

Comment: Ah, `HtmlXPathSelector` is deprecated. I had to go look it up because I've never seen it used. You should definitely switch to using `Selector.xpath()`.

It sounds like the tutorial/resource you're learning Scrapy from is out of date for the version of Scrapy you are using. I highly recommend the [Official Scrapy Tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) if you haven't seen it yet.

Comment: am not able to import Selector ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415089/from-scrapy-selector-import-selector-error

Comment: What version of Scrapy are you using? `scrapy version` will tell you. I suspect the version of Scrapy you are on is too old for Selectors. Regardless, you can probably still use `contains(@id, 'results_')` in your HtmlXPathSelector to get the data you want...

Comment: can u show how to use contains with HtmlXPathSelector  ? it throws the following error `            divs = hxs.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'result_')]")
        exceptions.AttributeError: 'HtmlXPathSelector' object has no attribute 'xpath'`

Comment: it worked : divs = hxs.select("//*[contains(@id, 'result_')]") .. thanks

Comment: If you upgrade to the latest Scrapy version, you'll be able to use regular expressions: `hxs.select("//*[re:test(@id, 'result_\d+')]")`

Comment: Thanks Paul, that is an awesome feature that I was not aware of!

Comment: It's a feature we added a few months ago, along CSS selectors, but we haven't advertized it much. It relies on lxml's EXSLT support