# scrapy 0.16,response is having no attribute selector,xpath()

Tags: scrapy, response, web-crawler

I have searched on google and seen questions on Stack overflow too, but nothing is working. I have gone through

- [from scrapy.selector import selector error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415089/from-scrapy-selector-import-selector-error)
- also read a suggestion to `from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector` 
  but nothing worked,

> **response.body** and **response.headers** are working well however **response.selector** and **response.xpath()** is giving error saying that no such attribute exists for the response object

I am not able to import Selector too,because there is no `Selector` in the scrapy directory hierarchy(don't know why)

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            title = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            link = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            desc = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            print title, link, desc
```

I am using **SCRAPY 0.16** (working with *Django Dynamic Scraper*,so can't update because it is compatible only with this version only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking at the documentation for the latest version. There have been quite a few changes since 0.16. You should be looking at the documentation for 0.16 http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16

Your example should look like this:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
        for site in sites:
            title = site.select('a/text()').extract()
            link = site.select('a/@href').extract()
            desc = site.select('text()').extract()
            print title, link, desc
```

As described in the tutorial http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/intro/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks lot for looking into this..........Thanks Again...the link was helpful too.. **:)**